# Android 4.0 devices do not return majority of the discoverable Bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-nexus-s, samsung-galaxy-nexus, samsung

The observation about 4.0 may be wrong, but this s evident in both the 4.0 devices I have tested : [Samsung Galaxy Nexus](http://www.google.co.in/nexus/) and [Samsung Nexus S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_S). (Nexus S is actually upgraded by me to 4.0)
In the other devices (HTC-Evo and ZTE-Optik), this problem is not there, compelling me to suspect 4.0 ; or Samsung as vendor.

The list of devices it is successfully able to scan have no "pattern" - it is random. It discovers the same device in one scan and may not do so the next time. **Maximum 50%** of the total devices in the vicinity are discovered.

**EDIT : (Added more details)**

The devices are close enough and the RSSI values are all > 60 dBm
All the "missing" devices are getting discovered through devices < 4.0.

To add some more details, I must say the problem is not with the "other" devices - the same device shows up in one scan and fails to show in other (on Android 4.0)
When I say scan - I only mean scanning through startDiscovery() in my code. If I do the scan via Device Settings, then all the devices are enlisted BUT many of them are only cached values - once I try connecting to some device, it says "Device not in range".

Any solutions ?

Comment: That could also mean something's broken with your radio image. I've encountered a similar behaviour with Wifi after upgrading my HTC Buzz from stock 2.1 to CM7: APs are listed on scan, but when I try to connect *one* they are suddenly *all* "not in range" (though still displayed in the list). If I leave the device alone for 10..30min, it finally auto-connects to my network. Though in my case it is Wifi (I use no BT), it sounds very similar.

Comment: So why "radio"? Most (not all) people who had the described Wifi problem got if fixed by re-flashing the radio image.